# Taking pointer to member std::string::size fails to link with libc++ but works with libstdc++

Tags: c++, stdstring, libc++, missing-symbols

I'm on a project where I need to use libc++. I'm come up with the following problem:

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string::size_type (std::string::*function)() const = &std::string::size;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

If I use the libstdc++ instead of libc++ I get no errors so the issue should to be related with libc++.

Full output below:

```
clang++ --stdlib=libc++ -v main.cpp 
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 241.9 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0 --stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/filipe/Downloads -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 197 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/8k/34ll5dcj3c5c9sph_bwk1zr00000gn/T/main-5b89bb.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0 based upon LLVM 3.5svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o a.out /var/folders/8k/34ll5dcj3c5c9sph_bwk1zr00000gn/T/main-5b89bb.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::size() const", referenced from:
      _main in main-5b89bb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could you add the command line you are compiling with? Based on Shafik's answer, its probably a compiler bug. But I'd still be interested in the compiler invocation.

Comment: I am guessing the close voter tried this on coliru and could not reproduce, a comment would have been helpful though.

Comment: @jww The command I used is on the full output: clang++ --stdlib=libc++ -v main.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a `libc++` bug by this thread: [_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY and std::string::length](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/LIBCPP-INLINE-VISIBILITY-and-std-string-length-td4030879.html)  which doing something similar and Howard Hinnant's response is:

> I believe this is due to a poor interaction in the compiler between
>   extern templates and __attribute__ ((__always_inline__)).  If
>   std::string is not declared extern template, then the compiler will
>   outline a size() member and you won't get this link error.
>
> In my opinion, clang should not assume that extern templates have
>   definitions for inlined members, especially those marked
>   always_inline, and the fact that it does is a clang bug resulting in
>   the link error you see.
>
> The rationale for the use of always_inline in libc++ is to control the
>   ABI of libc++.  In the past I have watched compilers use different
>   heuristics from release to release on making the inline/outline
>   decision.  This can cause code to be silently added to and removed
>   from a dylib.  With the use of always_inline, I am telling the
>   compiler to never add that code to the libc++.dylib binary.
>
> Each of the macros defined and used by libc++ can be overridden.
>
> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY controls how an inlined function is attributed and defaults to:
>
> ```
> #ifndef _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
> #define _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __attribute__ ((__visibility__("hidden"), __always_inline__))
> #endif
> ```
>
> You can turn this off with:
>
> -D_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY=""
>
> And extern templates are done with:
>
> ```
> #ifndef _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
> #define _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(...) extern template __VA_ARGS__;
> #endif
> ```
>
> This latter one is more difficult to "turn off".  The incantation is:
>
> -D'_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(...)='
>
> Using either (or both) of these workarounds will silence your link
>   error.  But a bug report against clang might be a better long term
>   solution.

I can not reproduce this on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) but I can on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/85cHKaoAMcIGEa6X) and using optimization which uses the `-O2` flag makes the problem go away. I was not able to make wandbox accept the `-D` options suggested above, so not sure if that works.

On my local machine Howard's solution works:

```
clang++ -D_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY="" -D'_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(...)='
```

I have not found a bug report, if I don't find one it may make sense to file one.

Comment: This is great information. It allowed me to find more details on extern templates. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After looking into Shafik Yaghmour information, I found a solution that doesn't require modifying the compilation flags.

The solution is forcing the compiler to instantiate the extern template class. The final code is the following:

```
#include <string>

template class std::basic_string<char>;

int main()
{
    std::string::size_type (std::string::*function)() const = &std::string::size;
    return 0;
}
```

More information here: [using extern template (C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c0x)

Comment: Building with `-O2` or greater also fixed the problem for me, did you attempt this?